# Bill Me Later Implementation via REST, or only in Classic API?

Tags: rest, paypal

Paypal offers some pretty nice RESTful APIs for deep integration with a shopping cart, but I'm having a hard time discovering whether or not "Bill Me Later" is available via this API.  After digging in, it appears Bill Me Later is only available in the classic API.  Is this true, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish Paypal made this more clear, but Bill Me Later is actually an option presented to Express Checkout users. So if you implement Express Checkout (I don't think it would be limited to Classic) AND the user is selected by Paypal, they will be asked to use/sign-up for BML.